# How to call objects that were cloned

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, cloning

I clone a panel and its contents(A image and a checkbox) 20 times.

Sample of the panel being cloned:

[image]

This is the procedure used to clone a whole panel:

```
procedure TForm1.ClonePanel(pObjectName: Tpanel);
var   apanel : Tpanel;
  Ctrl, Ctrl_: TComponent;
  i: integer;
 begin
  //handle the Control itself first
   TComponent(apanel) := CloneComponent(pObjectName);
    with apanel do
    begin
     Left := 24;
     Top :=64;
    end;

  //now handle the childcontrols
  for i:= 0 to pObjectName.ControlCount-1 do
   begin
    Ctrl := TComponent(pObjectName.Controls[i]);
    Ctrl_ := CloneComponent(Ctrl);
    TControl(Ctrl_).Parent := apanel;
    TControl(Ctrl_).Left := TControl(Ctrl).Left;
    TControl(Ctrl_).top := TControl(Ctrl).top;
  end;

end;
```

The following is the the code that physically does the cloning(called above):

```
function TForm1.CloneComponent(AAncestor: TComponent): TComponent;
var
    XMemoryStream: TMemoryStream;
    XTempName: string;
  begin
    Result:=nil;
    if not Assigned(AAncestor) then
      exit;
    XMemoryStream:=TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      XTempName:= AAncestor.Name;
      AAncestor.Name:='clone_' + XTempName + inttostr(panels);
      inc(panels);
      XMemoryStream.WriteComponent(AAncestor);
      AAncestor.Name:=XTempName;
      XMemoryStream.Position:=0;
      Result:=TComponentClass(AAncestor.ClassType).Create(AAncestor.Owner);
      if AAncestor is TControl then TControl(Result).Parent:=TControl(AAncestor).Parent;
      XMemoryStream.ReadComponent(Result);
    finally
      XMemoryStream.Free;
    end;
end;
```

So now I want to use the cloned objects but how do I call them in my code?
 For example how can I call the checked function of one of the cloned check boxes?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Look them up by name, or remember the reference to the control. You should be using frames though rather than reinventing this particular wheel.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm not quite sure what what you mean by "Look them up by name"

Comment: Each component has `.Name()` property. You can use `FindComponent()` function to find component by its name.

Comment: I suggest that you use some more elegant approach, as David suggested too, instead recreating controls.

Comment: The thing is the panels are already contained within a frame.

Comment: Put the things you need to clone in a frame, and create multiple instances of that frame. Job done.

Comment: That's a very creative solution, but way confusing. Look up TFrame. It's like a TForm. A TPanel is not that. And there's no evidence of a TFrame in the above code. You create a TFrame and put a TPanel on it, then put whatever you want on the panel. Then create instances of the frame directly, like creating new instances of forms. Each instance is accessed like a form, only it's a frame.  You could also create a TForm that just has the panel on it and is shrunk way down, but that's more work than just using a TFrame.

Comment: So is it possible to create 20 frames within a frame? The panel being cloned is already contained in a frame.

Comment: Would this question make sense to you: So is it possible to create 20 forms within a form?  A TFrame is a container, like a TForm. You can define one and create a virtually unlimited number of instances of them. You can put 50 of them on a form. Hundreds if you want. On Panels, on tabsheets, on whatever you want. Think of them like pre-printed sticky notes. :)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks for your help I really appreciate it and especially for staying patient when I ask stupid questions. Just one more thing can you point me to somewhere where I can read on how to create multiple instances of a TFrame.

Comment: It's just like any other object. Use .Create()

Comment: This is a long-ass URL, so I shrunk it down: http://goo.gl/IAKKzF

Comment: http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2007/qt/tframe_oncreate.htm

Comment: http://delphi-kb.blogspot.com/2011/06/delphi-frames_14.html

Comment: http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.ide/200904/0904153170.html

Comment: Like this. In a loop do `Frames[i] := TMyFrame.Create(Self);`. Then you need to parent it and position it.

Comment: Another solution (other than TFrame) is to write a custom control based on TPanel (for example). a lot of fun... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others are right and it is better to use frame but if we want just use your code we must fix it first. there is a problem in your code and that is the `Inc(panles);` position. you must put this line after loop of `for i:= 0 to pObjectName.ControlCount-1 do` in the *ClonePanle* procedure, not in the *CloneComponent* function.

If you fix that, then you can use **FindComponent** function to access the components that you want as Marko Paunovic said.

For example the name of the component that you put on the first Panel that you defined as the first instance which other cloned panels are cloned from that is *TestCheckBox*. If you cloned 20 times the Panel that we talked about; you can access the TCheckBox of the 16th Cloned obejct like this and changing it's caption to whatever you want: 
(I suppose that the panels variable was 0, when the program started.)

```
TCheckBox(FindComponent('clone_TestCheckBox15')).Caption:='aaaaa';
```

Comment: TFrame may well be the way forward but take a moment to understand what a TDBCtrlGrid can do for you too;  One of these connected to a TClientDataset can be very powerful indeed.